# ghostscript command line arguments printer selection in ps file

Tags: printing, ghostscript

I am using a c# wrapper to batch print pdf files without user interaction. I am using a ps file which is created dynamically by c# wrapper and Iprovide that ps file as process start args. The reason for use a ps file is gs does not support dynamic user friendly spooler name as command line args. he problem is gs does not automatically select the printer when I am using ps file. It always asks to select printer manually. here is the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        try
        {
            string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\wd.print";
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
            string[] content = sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            sr.Close();

            string printer = content[0];

            for (int i = 1; i < content.Length; ++i)
            {
                ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();


                psInfo.Arguments = String.Format(" setup.ps -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sOutputFile=\"\\\\spool\\{0}\" \"{1}\"",
                   printer,
                   content[i]);


                String spoolerName = content[i].Substring(content[i].IndexOf("$")+1);
                //creates the dynamic ps file named setup.ps
                generateSettings(spoolerName);
                string gs = Application.StartupPath + @"\gs\gswin32c.exe"; ;
                psInfo.FileName = gs;
                psInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                Process process = Process.Start(psInfo);
                process.WaitForExit();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    protected static void generateSettings(String name)
    {
        //the code which creates the dynamic ps file named setup.ps
        FileStream file=File.Create("setup.ps");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
        writer.WriteLine("mark");
        writer.WriteLine("  /NoCancel true ");
        writer.WriteLine("  /UserSettings");
        writer.WriteLine("   <<");
        writer.WriteLine("    /DocumentName (" + name + ")");//custom name for windows print spooler
        writer.WriteLine("   >>"); 
        writer.WriteLine("  (mswinpr2) finddevice");
        writer.WriteLine("  putdeviceprops");
        writer.WriteLine("setdevice");

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        file.Close();




    }
}
```

please help me . I want to select the printer automatically so it does not want user intervention

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the .PS file then send the data to the printer of your choosing via this mechanism: [How to send raw data to a printer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091).  You can get a list of printer, select it programtically, then send the .PS to the device.  When you send the file you can specify what appears in the spooler / job name.